# Implementing user generated JavaScript for calculations using AngularJS templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Use Case

Our current application allows the user access to a form. In this form, there is a variety of form elements, which the user can perform calculations against. The current application allows the end-user to write **any** JavaScript they desire to manipulate the data. We want to move away from this because the end user can manipulate the DOM and do all sorts of nasty stuff. The idea is to use Angular templates to store and perform the calculations.

The requirements are that the end user should be able to create a calculation using:

- any form input available through the `name` property
- all standard operators (+, /, %, -, etc...)
- any methods in the `Math` and `Date` JavaScript Objects

### Example

I currently have a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pt38y/), but it doesn't update in real-time. When the user enters a formula within the `input` bound to `template`, the calculation does not appear in the `output`.

As an example, the variable `addition` could be a formula created by an end-user and retrieved from the database. However, changes to the formula `addition` are also not reflected in real-time.

### Code

#### Angular Template

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <ng-form name="myForm">
        <label>
            <span>A:</span>
            <input type="number" name='a' ng-model="data.a" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>B:</span>
            <input type="number" name='b' ng-model="data.b" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Template:</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="template" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Output of A+B:</span>
            <input type="output" ng-value="{{ addition }}" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Output of {{ template }}:</span>
            <input typue="output" ng-value="{{ template }}" />
        </label>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var ctrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.data = { a: 5, b: 6 };
    $scope.template = '';
    $scope.addition = 'myForm.a.$modelValue + myForm.b.$modelValue';
};
```

### Questions

- Can the system be exploited using AngularJS templates?
- Can calculations be updated in real-time?
- Is there a safer method to implement client-generated JavaScript? (I found `ADSafe`, but need to investigate this more)

Comment: Seems like it would be simpler to just have your end users write an Angualr expression on the data and you could just use that literal text as an expression and evaluate it against your scope. Not sure if that is an option but with Angular your job would be almost done.

Comment: For example ... http://plnkr.co/edit/IXSwCJpTf4g6iO6ynMrr?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to elevate comment to an answer. Templates not needed. You can achieve what you want using $scope.$eval. Math and Date functions can be added as well very simply.

http://plnkr.co/edit/IXSwCJpTf4g6iO6ynMrr?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.16"   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="test">
    <h1>{{test}}</h1>

<p>
  <input ng-change="eval(expr)" ng-model="a"  type='number'/>
  <input ng-change="eval(expr)" ng-model="b"  type='number'/>
</p>

<textarea  ng-model="expr" ng-change="eval(expr)">
</textarea>

<span>{{ans}}</span>

<script>
  var app=angular.module("app",[]);
  app.controller("test",function($scope){
    $scope.test="hello world";

    $scope.Math = Math;

    $scope.Date=function(str){
      return new Date(str)
    }

    /*RegExp('[1-9]+').test(b)*/
    $scope.RegExp = function(patternStr,flags){
      return new RegExp(patternStr,flags);
    }

    $scope.eval =function(v){
      var ans 
      try{
      $scope.ans=$scope.$eval(v);
      }catch(e){}
    }
  });

  angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't know about the $eval function. This is great, definitely looks like a safe way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my original answer to provide better support for Dates, and added support for Regular Expressions as well. Very Straightforward on extending this approach to support the susbset of objects and functions you wish to provide to your user.

Comment: This should go in a wiki somewhere. This is definitely a very valuable pattern.